# How to list the values according to selected value from select option

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have 2 drop down menu, let it be:

```
<select name="" id="district" onchange="selectbyDistrict()">
    <option value="one">1</option>
    <option value="two">2</option>
    <option value="three">3</option>
</select>
```

And for Next drop down menu, I have to retrive from database and display according to the selected values of above options

I use script as

```
$('#district').change(function(){
    var value = $('#district').val();
    $.get('get_ajax.php', {id:value}, function(data){ 
        $('#new_location').html(data);
    }); 
});
```

In `get_ajax.php` code `var_dump($_GET);` display nothing.

So How to complete this. Please Suggest me

 **Many Thanks in Advance**

Comment: Remove `onchange="selectbyDistrict()"` and check.. Do you find any error in console ?

Comment: When making a GET query, you need to change the URL to have your values included; You should be querying the following URL: `"get_ajax.php?id=" + value`

Comment: @RayonDabre No error in console and why to remove `onchange="selectbyDistrict()"`

Comment: @Hugo can u plz suggest me the code in detail

Comment: @Hugo, You are quiet wrong mate..Read this [[ref](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)]

Comment: @yank, If you are binding event using `jQ`, why do you need `inline-event-binding` ? Can you `console.log(value)` ?

Comment: Ohh! I got an erron in console "`Password fields present on an insecure (http://) page. This is a security risk that allows user login credentials to be stolen. 

0`"

Comment: @RayonDabre I understand that jQuery allows for sending data in the data field, however I have had issues in the past when using this method and found it easier to just manually write the URL with the variables I want to send

Comment: @Hugo, I will appreciate if you can share those with us or SO question regarding that! I am quiet certain that is not related with that ? How will you frame a query string if you have 50 parameters ? Will be quiet ugly right ?

Comment: @RayonDabre I assume jQuery is building this URL in the same way as this is the only way to pick up the variables from the PHP side when making a query, thus typing out the URL (while it may be a less attractive method) is just as effective

Comment: I can't upload image due to few reputation. I also got `GET http://www.egharjagga.com/get_ajax.php?id=one` in console

Comment: @Yank, So what is the question ?

Comment: @Hugo, Yes! It will work the same way.. But why would the code provided by OP will fail! _It will not!_

Comment: @RayonDabre I tried v`var_dump($_GET); die();` in page `get_ajax.php` but i can't get any outpur

Comment: @RayonDabre good point. haha

Comment: @yank, `array(1) { ["id"]=> string(3) "one"` => _You are getting it mate!_

Comment: @RayonDabre yes, M getting. Bt nothng in `get_ajax.php` or `id=new_location` after return

Comment: share html for `#new_location`;

Comment: Are u talking about dynamic combo-box?

Comment: And Next thing I tried `var value = $('#district').val(); alert(value);` it will not alert anything in first select, it will alert one time in second time i select the list,  it will alert 2 time same value I select the value from list and so on

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="" id="district" onchange="selectbyDistrict(this)">
    <option value="one">1</option>
    <option value="two">2</option>
    <option value="three">3</option>
</select>
```

Now Right the code for onchange Event And also include the ajax

```
function selectbyDistrict(obj){
        var selectedValues = obj.value;



       $.ajax({  method: "POST",
                 url: "district_subpart.php",
                 data: {'district':selectedValues}
             }).success(function( msg ) {

                    // this is place you can right where you want to display
         });

}
```

Now on the php File You right the code

```
district_subpart.php

$district = $_POST['district'];

// Mysql Connect Here

    mysql_connect("hostname","mysql_username","mysql_password");
    mysql_select_db("database_name");

    $sql = "select * from district_subpart where district_id = ".$district;

    $results = mysql_query($sql);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($results)){
        // right here code 
    } 


    die;
```